# android nexus 7 can't find octave home directory

Tags: android, matlab, octave, home-directory

I've installed Octave for Android on my Nexus 7 running Adroid 5.1.1.  I can even run a trivial plot from a command I typed by hand in the terminal emulator.

Octave comes up saying my home directory can be found at /storage/emulated/0/GNUOctave/home.  I mount my Nexus 7 on my windows machine as a media device where the only volume that shows up is called "Internal storage"  I look around and search and can't find even "emulated" in internal storage, and searching on "octave" gets me a folder with a patch in it but no closer to my home folder.

pwd in the terminal emulator only shows me "/home"

Looking at file system in ES Explorer on the Nexus 7, I **can** find my Octave home.  It is in a GNUOctave folder which is obviously at the top level of "Internal storage" but is the only folder ES Explorer shows which does NOT show up in Explorer on my PC!

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid about this, but it did cost me an hour and I am not actually stupid.

I powered down the Nexus 7 and restarted it.  When it came back up, the GNUOctave folder showed up in explorer on my windows laptop and my problem is solved.